# Performance testing - analysing Graph results in Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, load-testing, stress-testing

Am new to Jmeter and I ran the test successfully. Now I'd like to understand what the results mean and what is classed as good/bad measurements, and what can be suggested to improve the results. Below is a table of the results collated in the Summary report of Jmeter.

Can anyone help me understand these results?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The **Throughput**: is the number of requests per unit of time (seconds, minutes, hours) that are sent to your server during the test.

The **Response time**: is the elapsed time from the moment when a given request is sent to the server until the moment when the last bit of information has returned to the client.

The **throughput** is the real load processed by your server during a run but it does not tell you anything about the performance of your server during this same run. This is the reason why you need both measures in order to get a **real idea** about your server’s performance during a run. The **response time** tells you how fast your server is handling a given load.

Now in this image, **Throughput = 8003.557/minute** means that (~133/second Requests) are sent to your tested server.

**Average=287**: This is the Average (Arithmetic mean μ = 1/n * Σi=1…n xi) Response time of your total samples.
**An important** thing to understand is that the mean value can be very **misleading** as it does not show you how close (or far) your values are from the average.For this purpose, we need the **Deviation** value since Average value can be the Same for different response time of the samples!!

**Deviation=405**:  The **standard deviation (σ)** measures the mean distance of the values to their average (μ).It gives you a good idea of the **dispersion or variability** of the measures to their mean value.

The following equation show how the **standard deviation (σ)** is calculated:

**σ = 1/n * √ Σi=1…n (xi-μ)2**

For Details, see [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html)!!

So, if the deviation value is **low compared** to the mean value, it will indicate you that your measures are not dispersed (or mostly close to the mean value) and that the mean value is **significant**.

**Latest Sample=33**: This is the Latest samples **Response time (33 ms)**!!!

**No of samples=1800**: Total number of samples are showing here during the Test!!!

An example is always better to understand!!! I think, this [article](https://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/) will help you.

Remember, **Graph Results are only Graphical representation** of these mathematical measurements!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I am not so well versed in Jmeter, but I once studied it for few months. Here are some of the good links I can recommend for interpreting Jmeter results.

- [Link 1](http://www.coderanch.com/t/561221/Testing/Read-JMeter-graphs-results) - check Andrew Monkhouse's answer. He has explained it very precisely.
- [Link 2](http://www.datazoo.de/articles/158/performance-testing-analyzing-jmeter-results) - A good explanation is given here.
- [Link 3](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/tip/Tips-for-interpreting-JMeter-results) - TechTarget always have some of the best explanations. This is another one for Jmeter graphs.

Comment: Thanks log_file...I didn't found any clear explanation on Graph Result Listener